# How to format (write) XML strings in Eclipse in multiple rows?

Tags: android, xml, formatting

I can't find if there is a way to write very long strings in XML in multiple lines without affecting string behavior in the code.

I have FAQ section and Answers to some questions are EG 3-4 sentences, some 400 characters long. So for each "Enter" ("Return") that I've pressed in my Strings file, I get new paragraph when displaying this in the app.

I've read here that concatenation is not working, but I do not really need it, I need to escape new paragraph that occurs when enter is pressed.

Comment: do you are talking about not beeing able to paste the long string in Eclipse(scipping characters) or in your App? It is a bit unclear to me what your problem is. If possible post a screenshot :)

Comment: I'm talking about Eclipse. XML with Strings. If you have a long long long string, and want to be able to read it, if you put "enter" (new line) it ends up with new paragraph in the Application.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use \n:

```
<string name="about_message">
    Line1\nLine2\nLine3
</string>
```

Comment: Exactly opposite :) I'm aware of new line indent (\n) which CREATES new line when app is running, but I'd like to format my text within XML that I do not have to scroll from left to right, and avoid new lines, tabs or paragraphs.